# How to pass params with devise_invitable?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, devise-invitable

**Goal**

I would like to let a user.admin invite a user to only one of its hotels with the devise_invite gem.

=> Users and Hotels are connected via a Join_table UserHotel.

**Issue**

I am not able to create the user_hotel Join_table and/ord add the specific hotel params to the invited user.

- controller
  `>> @user.hotels => #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []>`
- console:

```
pry(main)> User.invitation_not_accepted.last.hotels
  User Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."invitation_token" IS NOT NULL AND "users"."invitation_accepted_at" IS NULL ORDER BY "users"."id" DESC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
  Hotel Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "hotels".* FROM "hotels" INNER JOIN "user_hotels" ON "hotels"."id" = "user_hotels"."hotel_id" WHERE "user_hotels"."user_id" = $1  [["user_id", 49]]
=> []
```

**UPDATE**

The issue seems to be in the many-to-many relationship between user and hotel. When I break my controller 'new' action after `hotel.user.new` and test it I het the following:

- `>> @user.hotels => #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []>`
- `>> @hotel.users => #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<User id: 2, email: "test@hotmail.com", created_at: "2019-11-05 14:17:46", updated_at: "2019-11-05 15:04:22", role: "admin">, #<User id: nil, email: "", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, role: "admin">]>`

**Note**
I set up users with devise, such that my users controller is build up as:

- users/confirmations_controller.rb
- users/invitations_controller.rb
- users/omniauth_callbacks_controller.rb
- users/password_controller.rb
- users/registrations_controller.rb
- users/sessions_controller.rb
- users/unlocks_controller.rb

**Code**

routes

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  devise_for :users

  resources :hotels do
devise_for :users, :controllers => { :invitations => 'users/invitations' }
  end
end
```

models

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable, :trackable and :omniauthable
  has_many :user_hotels, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :hotels, through: :user_hotels
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :user_hotels
  enum role: [:owner, :admin, :employee]
  after_initialize :set_default_role, :if => :new_record?

  def set_default_role
    self.role ||= :admin
  end

  devise :invitable, :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable, :invitable
end

class UserHotel < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :hotel
  belongs_to :user
end

class Hotel < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :user_hotels, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :users, through: :user_hotels
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :users, allow_destroy: true, reject_if: ->(attrs) { attrs['email'].blank? || attrs['role'].blank?}
end
```

views/hotels/show

`<%= link_to "invite new user", new_user_hotel_invitation_path(@hotel)%>`

controllers/users/invitations_controller.rb

```
class Users::InvitationsController < Devise::InvitationsController
  def new
    @hotel = Hotel.find(params[:hotel_id])
    @user = @hotel.users.new
  end

  def create
    @hotel = Hotel.find(params[:hotel_id])
    @user = @hotel.users.new(hotel_user_params)
    @user.invite!
  end

  private
  def hotel_user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:email, :role,
      hotel_users_attributes: [:hotel_id])
  end
end
```

views/invitations/new.html.erb

```
<h2><%= t "devise.invitations.new.header" %></h2>

<%= simple_form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: user_hotel_invitation_path(@hotel), html: { method: :post }) do |f| %>  <%= f.error_notification %>

  <% resource.class.invite_key_fields.each do |field| -%>
    <div class="form-inputs">
      <%= f.input field %>
    </div>
  <% end -%>

      <%= f.input :role, collection: [:owner, :admin, :employee] %>
  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.button :submit, t("devise.invitations.new.submit_button") %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: If you nested the invitations controller in the hotels directory you could then have access to the hotel id. At which point you could do `hotel = Hotel.find(params[:id])` and then `user = hotel.users.new(....)` and then invite with `user.invite!` This _should_ set up the relationships for you since when you use `invite!` is saves the record

Comment: Thanks for your response/input, that was really helpful:) Under hotel, I now added ```devise_for :users, :controllers => { :invitations => 'users/invitations' }```, which indeed provides me with the proper hotel_id. However, somehow I am not able to create the Join_table & consequently add the park to the user (see also my updated question).

Comment: Sorry, also you should be doing the new/create in the users controller. Devise's Invitable controller handles the flow for after they click the invitation link. Also, you can pass attributes to the `new`. ie `@user = @hotel.users.new(hotel_user_params)` , `@user.invite!`. That happens in the create action in the users controller. Devise handles the flow after t hey click the accept invitation link

Comment: Thank again;) What do you mean with "also you should be doing the new/create in the users controller."? I build my users controller with devise (```users/confirmations_controller.rb```, ```users/invitations_controller.rb```, ```users/confirmations_controller.rb```, ```users/sessions_controller.rb``` etc.). The way I built up my invitations_controller now is still in the devise_invitable controller (new & create).

Comment: Think the problem lies with the many to many relationship between hotels and users... (See also the updated question). Somehow it's not building the relationship in the new action.

Comment: You can try build instead of new. https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/CollectionProxy/build